# Multiple File Associations in VSCode for Mixed PHP and JS Syntax Highlighting

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have a file, source.php, that contains Javascript after the closing PHP tag.  Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code do syntax highlighting/completion on the Javascript code.  It currently only highlights the PHP code.

It'd be great if settings.json supported something like the following:

```
"files.associations": {
    "source.php": ["javascript", "php"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible without writing your own VSCode extension to understands the combined file

For syntax highlighting, you'd need to define a new grammar that combines the php and javascript grammars.

Completions are even more complicated. You need a language server / extension that can understand the new combined document. How our html server handles script blocks is probably the best example of this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/html/server/src/modes/javascriptMode.ts

Answer (score -1):

This extension could help.
[One Dark Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andischerer.theme-atom-one-dark)

It is based in this Git Repo : https://github.com/atom/one-dark-syntax